# ¿Como leer columnas vacías o en blanco de un archivo de excel con la librería OleDb?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, excel

Al hacer la lectura de un archivo de excel con la librería OleDb, me devuelve solamente las columnas que contienen datos.

Estoy usando estas cadenas de conexión para los xls y xlsx

```
if (extension.Trim() == ".xls")
        {
            // XLS - Excel 2003 and Older
            props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
            props["Extended Properties"] = "'Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=3'";
            props["Data Source"] = path;
        }
        else
        {
            // XLSX - Excel 2007, 2010, 2012, 2013

            props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
            props["Extended Properties"] = "'Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=No;IMEX=3;'";
            props["Data Source"] = path;
        }
```

Y para leer los datos de la hoja, lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 11000 * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.TableName = sheetName;
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

da.Fill(dt);
```

Por ejemplo si la columna A viene vacía, solo me lee de la columna B en adelante.

Necesito leer las columnas vacías para poder hacer un mapeo a partir de los parámetros que manda el usuario.

¿De que manera puedo forzar a que también se lea las columnas vacías?

Comment: Yo también lo necesito, ¿Encontraste algo? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Intentaste definir las columnas que quieres recuperar, por supuesto la primer row deberia representar los nombres de las columnas, entonces usarias

```
SELECT ID,City,State FROM [sheetName$]
```

[Reading and Writing Excel Spreadsheets Using ADO.NET C# DbProviderFactory](https://elemirac.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/read-write-excel-ado/)

para definir la primer row con los nombres asigna `HDR=Yes`

Al tener la primer row de las columnas con los nombres deberia poder leer a pesar que este vacia

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!!! El problema es que los archivos de excel son muchos, y varian mucho, entonces los parametros que manda el usuario los utilizo para hacer el mapeo de la información. Ya intenté leer por rango por ejemplo: A1:F1000 y si la columna A viene vacia, igualmente me la excluye. ¿Conoces alguna otra forma con la que pudiera incluir esa columna vacia sin modificar el archivo?